# Why does the period of precession of a gyroscope have to be way larger than it's spin period so that it's motion can be modelled?

Tags: angular-momentum, torque, rotational-kinematics, gyroscopes, precession

Mathematically, torque induced gyroscopic precession may be modelled with the following equation:

$$
{\displaystyle T_{\mathrm {p} }={\frac {4\pi ^{2}I_{\mathrm {s} }}{\ mgrT_{\mathrm {s} }}}={\frac {4\pi ^{2}I_{\mathrm {s} }\sin(\theta )}{\ \tau T_{\mathrm {s} }}}}
$$

However, most sources that give this equation also state that the period of spin of the rotor (Ts) must be considerably smaller than the period of precession
(Tp) for the equation to model a valid relationship. However, these sources also don't give a reason as to why this is. Is this related to nutation and is there a more general formula that can be derived to model gyroscopic precession at the extremities?

Comment: It does not have to be: it's just that the equations are way more compicated. See  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/99f271d601bb3d9d04e8b8ce0c73cb7a_MIT16_07F09_Lec30.pdf

Comment: If there are more complicated equations in describing gyroscopic motion, what are the simplifications assumed that lead to the derivation of this equation? (found the derivation on https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-osuniversityphysics/chapter/11-3-precession-of-a-gyroscope/)

Comment: They are just that $\dot\psi\gg \dot \theta$ where $\theta$ and $\psi$ are the usual Euler angles.